# Como exibir somente mês e ano oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

então, estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios, e em um determinado, me pede para fazer uma consulta que retorne o valor total de uma coluna, e que esses valores sejam agrupados por mês e ano, mas a coluna de datas possui dia também. como exibir apenas `(mm/yyyy)`.

```
select 
  max(nr_pedido), 
  sum(vl_total), 
  dt_locacao 
from loc_pedido_locacao
group by dt_locacao;
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL ou Oracle? Vou assumir Oracle uma vez que aparece no assunto e que o campo que contém a data é dt_locacao.

Se este campo for do tipo date:

```
SELECT
  MAX(nr_pedido),
  SUM(vl_total),
  TO_CHAR(dt_locacao, 'YYYY-MM')
FROM loc_pedido_locacao
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dt_locacao, 'YYYY-MM');
```

Se o campo for do tipo CHAR temos duas hipótese. As duas pressupõem que o formato da data é fixo. Vou presumir que o formato da data é 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Converter de char para date e de volta para char:

```
SELECT
  MAX(nr_pedido),
  SUM(vl_total),
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt_locacao, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM')
FROM loc_pedido_locacao
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(dt_locacao, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'YYYY-MM');
```

Extrair o valor da data directamente da string:

```
SELECT
  MAX(nr_pedido),
  SUM(vl_total),
  SUBSTR(dt_locacao, 0, 7)
FROM loc_pedido_locacao
GROUP BY SUBSTR(dt_locacao, 0, 7);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno amigo, o primeiro select ja resolveu meu problema, ainda sou novo no oracle sql, to enfrentando alguns dilemas de lógica/ funções pré definidas.. poderia me dizer em quais casos eu devo utilizar o to_char? ele é aplicavel em quais condições?

Comment: O `TO_CHAR` é uma função de transformação. Transforma um tipo de dados (date, int, etc) em char e deve aplicar-se sempre que se pretenda esse tipo de transformação.